# React: How to change the state of a counter based on the current page scrolled

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to know the best way to change the state of a counter for different sections of a page whenever a user scrolls through each section of a page. The counter starts from one as the default. So when a user scrolls through 70% of the current section, the counter is incremented. This is similar to the section counter available on this link https://demo.cocobasic.com/volos-html/. This is what I have attempted so far. This actually works. But It's quite ugly and not responsive across all screen sizes. Please help I have been on this for a couple of days.

```
const [pageCounter, setPageCounter] = React.useState(1);

React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", (e) => {        
         if (window.pageYOffset < 485) {
            setPageCounter(1);
         }

        if (
          window.pageYOffset >= 485 &&
          window.pageYOffset < 2730
        ) {
          setPageCounter(2);
        }

        if (
          window.pageYOffset >= 2730 &&
          window.pageYOffset < 4940
        ) {
          setPageCounter(3);
        }

        if (
          window.pageYOffset >= 4940 &&
          window.pageYOffset < 6880
        ) {
          setPageCounter(4);
        }

        if (
          window.pageYOffset >= 6880 &&
          window.pageYOffset < 8490
        ) {
          setPageCounter(5);
        }

        if (window.pageYOffset >= 8490) {
          setPageCounter(6);
        }
      },
      false
    );
  }, [setPageCounter]);
```

Comment: What determines the `pageYOffset` "breakpoint" values? Just the length of content? Is this what you mean by "not responsive across screen sizes"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To address the "ugly" I would sort of treat the "breakpoints" as a "switch". Start with simply setting a default value, and then as each condition is met update to that value. It's OK to enqueue multiple state updates within a single render cycle, and as long as you are ***not*** using functional updates then each update will simply overwrite the previous enqueued update.

You should also return an effect clean up function to remove the scroll listener so you don't have a leak.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const scrollListener = (e) => {
    // [0, 485)
    setPageCounter(1);

    // [485, 2730)
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 485) {
      setPageCounter(2);
    }

    // [2730, 4930)
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 2730) {
      setPageCounter(3);
    }
    
    // [4930, 6880)
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 4930) {
      setPageCounter(4);
    }

    // [6880, 8490)
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 6880) {
      setPageCounter(5);
    }

    // [8490, infinity)
    if (window.pageYOffset >= 8490) {
      setPageCounter(6);
    }
  };

  window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollListener, false);

  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollListener, false);
}, [setPageCounter]);
```

This still has repeated patterns and could be more DRY.

```
React.useEffect(() => {
  const scrollListener = (e) => {
    const offsetYBreakpoints = [0, 485, 2730, 4930, 6880, 8490];

    offsetYBreakpoints.forEach((bp, index) => {
      window.pageYOffset >= bp && setPageCounter(index + 1);
    });
  };

  window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollListener, false);

  return () => window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollListener, false);
}, [setPageCounter]);
```

Once you answer question about what drives the `window.pageYOffset` "breakpoint" values we can derive a more responsive solution.

## Update with Responsive Measurement

Use a react ref to store an array of react refs that are attached to each section. Measure the DOM, get the top position and height of each section to compute the "breakpoints". Use these values to compare against the window's scroll position and window size.

1. React ref to hold array of refs attached to sections
2. Mounting `useEffect` to create and attach handlers for window resizing and scrolling
3. Function to measure the Sections to compute the array of breakpoints initially and on window resize
4. Function to handle scroll events

Code

```
const sectionsRef = React.useRef([]);

sectionsRef.current = [...Array(5).keys()].map(
  (_, i) => sectionsRef.current[i] ?? createRef()
);

useEffect(() => {
  let sectionBreakpoints = Array(5).fill(0);

  const measureSections = () => {
    sectionBreakpoints = sectionsRef.current.map((section) => {
      const { height, top } = section.current.getBoundingClientRect();
      return top + height * 0.7; // <-- height * 0.7 is 70% of section
    });
  };

  const scrollHandler = () => {
    const { innerHeight, scrollY } = window;

    sectionBreakpoints.forEach((bp, i) => {
      scrollY + innerHeight >= bp && setSectionCount(i + 1);
    });
  };

  window.addEventListener("resize", measureSections);
  window.addEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler, false);

  measureSections();
  scrollHandler();

  return () => {
    window.removeEventListener("resize", measureSections);
    window.removeEventListener("scroll", scrollHandler, false);
  };
}, []);
```

With this the array lengths are hardcoded, but presumably this is easy to manage, or it is up to use to dynamically allocate the array and refs.

Attach ref to section: `ref={sectionsRef.current[i]}`

[image: Edit jovial-thompson-06b42]

Comment: Hi Drew. The breakpoint of each section is determined by the length of the contents in each of the sections. So the counter should only be incremented after the user scrolls past 70% of the content of each section.

Comment: @HamedJimoh Are the lengths of each section known ahead of time? Can you provide a simple running codesanbox that has a bunch of sections?

Comment: Hi Drew. The height of the page is not known ahead of time. The height is only defined by the length of content sitting inside the section. Here is a simple codesandbox you requested: https://codesandbox.io/s/elegant-liskov-ipfcv

Comment: @HamedJimoh Took a bit longer to work out the kinks, but I believe I have a working solution for what you're after. I updated my answer.

Comment: Hi Drew. Thank you for this implementation. I just integrated your updated answer and it works very well for my use case.